# How to use recipient_delimiter with spamd and dovecot?

Tags: postfix, dovecot, spamd

I want to use `recipient_delimiter` to allow addresses like `user+anything@domain` in a setup involving spamd and dovecot.

I had a setup like this in the past with just using postfix, but with my setup using spamd and dovecot deliver it does not work as it seems that spamd/dovecot are searching for the mailbox `user+anything@domain` instead of `user@domain`.

The corresponding line in my `master.cf` is:

```
spamc     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -e /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

I [read](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/postfix-plus-addressing.htm) that the way to get it working with `maildrop` is

```
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=Debian-exim argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${user}@${nexthop}
  ${extension} ${recipient} ${user} ${nexthop}
```

But I do not get it working with `spamc` and deliver. Which of the variables is the correct one and are the programs parsing the `To` header on their own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here was to use `${user}@${domain}` as `${user}` does not automatically follow the username scheme (which is in my case `user@domain`) configured for postfix, but always contains the `user` part of a address in the form `user+foo@domain`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `dovecot-lda` like this:

```
dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop} -m ${extension}
```